# Calcular automáticamente el margin-top de un DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia a todos, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<div class="col-md-3 epub" style="margin-top: -157.3% ;margin-left: 79% ;">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="widget widget_search mt-1">
      <form action="search2.php" id="js" class="form-search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-wrapper" id="barraOcultar1">
          <input class="highlighted" id="js" name="js" placeholder="BUSCAR..." type="text" value="" style="width: 78%;height: 35px;">
          <input name="page" type="hidden" value="1">
          <button class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#ff1a00;" type="submit" name="enviar"><i class="fa fa-search" onclick="" style="background-color: #ff1a00 !important;"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">
      <h3 class="widget-title">Productos Recomendados</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="side1"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="side2"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="side3"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="side4"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Producto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="widget"><img id="publicidadLarge" src="https://misitio.com/img/publicidad/12.jpg" style="box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0px #000;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

lo que estoy intentando realizar es que la propiedad "margin-top" de el DIV que lleva como clase "col-md-3 epub" se calcule automáticamente, de momento tengo que hacerlo de manera manual en porcentaje, pero quisiera que se ajustara él mismo, imagino que para eso se debe obtener el alto y ancho de el div padre para poder calcular en base a eso la posición en la cual debe ajustarse, mas sin embargo desconozco como puedo realizar eso, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Comment: No está muy claro que es lo que quieres, que el margen se ajuste a que? al alto de la pantalla, del navegador? hace falta información.

Comment: Lamento la falta de detalles en mi pregunta, estoy necesitando que se ajuste al margen inicial de el DIV padre, en este caso seria el DIV contenedor de el que estoy mostrando en el código arriba.

Comment: Coloca el código junto con su contenedor padre para entender un poco más, y el css que estás usando, supongo que quieres calcular eso en base a la resolución de pantalla?

Comment: comparto contigo el siguiente enlace: https://ibb.co/9N7v8Sr en el cual esta la imagen de lo que estoy necesitando, utilice una linea color azul la cual muestra cual es el margin que debería tener el que sobre sale.

Comment: Sigo sin comprender, no encuentro porqué aplicaría un margin-top: -157.3%; en la imagen que muestras

Comment: el margin-top es para poder hacer llegar la caja que dice "buscar" al nivel de la linea colo azul que he trazado en la imagen que compartí, tiene que estar siempre en la misma posición, independientemente de el numero de elementos en ella, como puedes ver se trata de un catalogo de productos, cuando estos son igual a 12 en cuadriculas de 3x4 se ajusta perfectamente, pero cuando el numero es inferior pasa que se ve mal ajustado.

Comment: Por mas que trates de explicar y se logre entender, jamás podremos ayudarte a solucionar el problema si no muestras como está estructurado el código, ya que no sabemos para empezar, porque necesitas un margin negativo cuando no lo veo necesario a menos que estés usando mal el css o necesites sobreescribir código existente, pero como yo lo veo, para lo maquetado en la imagen, no necesito un margen negativo en ningun div, a menos que quiera sobreponer un div sobre otro, pero el diseño no lo requiere.